# Разные строки с одинаковым хэшем?

Tags: алгоритм, хеширование, комбинаторика, логика

Только что задумался - о комбинациях. 
Хэш, допустим md5 - это строка(латинский алфавит + цифры) длиной +-32 символов.
Но закинуть в хэш мы можем строку любого размера. Итого, комбинаций символов хэша существует намного меньше, чем скажем комбинации 60 символов. Значит, на все комбинации всех строк кеша из 32 символов не хватит. А это значит, что существуют строки, хэш которых одинаковый. (закон Дирихле)

Это мои 5-минутные рассуждения, не критикуйте строго, если что-то упустил. Просто стало очень интересно. Объясните мне, это хэширование не настолько идеальное, или я чего-то не знаю?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: Для хэшей и нет требования отсутствия коллизий, они не для этого нужны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну да, бывают коллизии хэш-сумм. Чем свежее (и длиннее на выходе) алгоритм хэширования, тем меньше вероятность, что для него найдется какая-то осмысленная коллизия.

Еще можете про [Радужные таблицы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0) полистать